# HASKELL Function nextLetter of alphabet

Tags: function, haskell, alphabet

I have to write a function in HASKELL whose name is siguienteLetra that take a variable and this variable is a letter of alphabet and return the next letter. How can i do that?

example: siguienteLetra 'a' and the function return me 'b' or siguienteLetra 'c' and the function return me 'd'

Comment: What have you tried? Have you poked around the documentation for the `Prelude` or any other modules in the `base` library yet?

Comment: What should sigiuenteLetra 'z' return? What about sigiuenteLetra '('?

Comment: The most succinct answer would be `succ`. It isn't a very enlightening answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hint 1

These two functions from `Data.Char` will be helpful:

```
ord :: Char -> Int
chr :: Int -> Char
```

The first one converts a character to its numerical representation (e.g. 'a' → 97, 'b' → 98) while the other does the reverse conversion (97 → 'a', 98 → 'b').
Using these function in a reasonable way will allow you to implement `siguienteLetra`.

### Hint 2

You will need a third function, besides `ord` and `chr`, what should it do?  This third function is in `Prelude`, but it *might* be difficult to guess its name (depending on your background). Fortunately, the function is very simple and you will easily write it yourself.

### Hint 3

What should be the signature of `siguienteLetra`?   Look at the signatures of your three functions (`ord`, `chr` and the third one) and think of the order in which they should be combined.

Comment: a lot of thanks i understand you now with these functions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Bolo thanks for your help, that is the result.

```
module Ejercicio1 where

import Data.Char
import Data.Ord()

siguienteLetra :: Char -> Char    -- you should not put pure computations
                                  -- in the IO Monad!
siguienteLetra y = chr z
 where x = ord y
       z = x+1

ejercicio1 :: IO ()
ejercicio1 = do
    y <- getChar
    print $ siguienteLetra y
```

Comment: I took the liberty of bringing this to a form that is actually proper Haskell style.

Comment: Keep in mind that this alone will not cycle for 'z' + 1 = 'a'. Therefore we need to expand the code a little bit. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20746730/1153801) answer.